# How to add while loop to randomizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to learn JavaScript and have made a website which randomizes gifs onclick from an array.

What I would like to do now is insert a while loop so that it will compare the currentgif to the next randomized image so no duplicates are shown but I can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong, most likely a syntax issue.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<html>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/rand.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <head>
        <title>Randomizer</title>
    </head>

    <body> 

        <p>This image is random</p>
        <a href="#" class="click">
            <section> 
                <img>
                    <script>
                        getRandomImage()
                    </script>
                </img>  
            </section>
        </a>

    </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var randomImage = new Array();

randomImage[0] = "images/1.gif";
randomImage[1] = "images/2.gif";
randomImage[2] = "images/3.gif";

function getRandomImage() { 
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
    document.write('<img src="'+randomImage[number]+'" />');
}

$(function() {
    $('a.click').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
        $(this).html('<img src="'+randomImage[number]+'" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Xero That's not his problem

Comment: @ntgCleaner I wasn't posting a answer, I was posting a comment...  Read the comment description...  "Suggest an improvement".

Comment: @xero, You're right.  You can suggest an improvement.  Like I could suggest you improve your comments to have more information, but that's off topic.  Your suggestion wasn't part of the OPs problem. I wouldn't ever suggest you were posting an answer either.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get which image it is:

```
function returnImgNum(){
    var imgNum = parseInt($('img').attr('src').split("/")[1].replace('.gif', ""));
    return imgNum;
}
```

Then make a loopable function (or just make a while loop, I like doing it this way)

```
function placeRand(number){
    if(number != returnImgNum()){
        document.write('<img src="'+randomImage[number]+'" />');
    } else {
        placeRand(number){
    }
}
```

Then add that comparator loop to your function:

```
function getRandomImage() { 
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomImage.length);
    placeRand(number);
}
```

Comment: This could get massively recursive if for some weird reason the random numbver remains the exact one (minimal chance!), potentially crashing the browser. Not really a problem here, but something to be aware of :)

Comment: You can counter the potential for undesired recursive-ness by creating an array to store all the previous randomly generated numbers and testing the new `number` against the values in the array.  This will prevent duplicates within a single load.  Once the array is the size of the number of images, you simply reset the array so the images can continue to cycle through.

Comment: Great point @AoN and Martijn, If the OP wants that, I will update the answer for sure

Answer (score 0):

```
var random_images_array = ['smile.gif', 'frown.gif', 'grim.gif', 'bomb.gif'];

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
path = path || 'images/'; // default path here
var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
var img = imgAr[ num ];
var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}
```

Check out this link. It tells you everything you need to know.

http://www.dyn-web.com/code/basics/random_image/random_img_js.php

Answer (score 0):

Create array, put inside all image names (or their indexes if it's better for you) and then use something like this:

```
var images = ["/first.png", "/second.png", "/third.png", "/fourth.png", "/fifth.png"];
function takeImage() {
  // if there is no more images in array, do something or return placeholder image
  //if (!images.length) doSomething(); 
  var image = images.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length), 1);
  return image[0];
}
```

Basically, this function on each call will return one random image name (or index if you want) until there will be no images left in this array.

Comment: No downvote because I like the different aproach, but array functions are relatively expensive to use and not needed, just access via key :)

Comment: I made it with array, because images named "1.gif","2.gif","3.gif" looks like very bad practice. And with array you can always use real world names or hashes at least.

Comment: I agree with the names, but `images[ RANDOM ]` would still be better :) And that is actually allready how th TS has it ;)

Comment: Yeah, now i get it :D And i remember now why i stopped any activity on stackoverflow, because understanding of "what user want" is really hard for me sometimes.

Comment: @NikolayTalanov I have just put '1.gif' as a filler but what would you recommend? 

IF I had a collection of 100 gifs or 1000 gifs, would it be bad practice to write them out in an array like that and pull it? Would there be a faster way to pull the images? 

I started this as a small project but now I am just trying to increase it in size as I learn so any direction is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, **you save the last image out of the function**. This makes a **global variable**. A global variable is a variable that exists in all functions, as a local variable only exists in the function itself (other functions cant use it).

```
// Define it outside of the function so the next time the called
// function gets it still has a value:
var lastNumber=0;
var imagesLength = randomImage.length; // don't recalc the amount of images every time
function getRandomImage(){ 
    var number=0; // start a local variable
    while( number == lastNumber){
        number = Math.floor(Math.random()*imagesLength );
    }
    document.write('<img src="'+randomImage[number]+'" />');
}
```

*To expand a bit on the local/global variables, `lastNumber` is global and can therefor be accessed in the function. `var number` however is local, it only exists in the function, `console.log(number);` outside the function would be `undefined`*

---

To make a suggestion for improvement, `document.write` is best to be avoided. Browsers don't like them (*can't find doc's to support, feel free to edit), pre-create an image, even if its blank:

```
<img id="RandomImage" src="transparant.png" />
```

Now you make a global variable (this can only be done if the javascript is loaded after the image in the source, or with a document ready) to store the image, and use that:

```
//  save reference to image, global (before the function):
var Image2Random = document.getElementById('RandomImage');
// place this instead of the document write.
Image2Random.src = randomImage[number];
```

This will be a lot faster. Javascript now knows what image to change, it doesn't have to create a new one every call (inserting elements to the DOM is expensive in resources), and the `.src` is really fast to change just the source.

Comment: Thanks for the response Martijn! 
This seems like the best approach for me as I can make sense of it haha.

When I copy and paste in the first block of code it still randomizes the same image more than once, do I have to change the image etc.. in the html or add in any other js aside from what you've written? 

Last question - If I wanted to have 100's or 1000's of gifs for instance, would an array such as writing it out 'randomImage[1125] = "images/gif.gif";' be a bad practice approach? why or why not? Would this approach affect load times? 

thanks again for the helpful advice!